# Make 'Asset Name' field unique

Tags: fields

We sell assets to clients with support contracts. All these assets need to have unique names which are generated according to a specific format. We imported all our assets in our SalesForce database and recently we found out that the [Asset].[Asset Name] field is not unique.

I can not find any way to make a specific field unique. Am I overlooking something?

If not is there maybe some way to enforce this using validation rules, or maybe with custom fields?

Answer (score 3):

- Create a text type field
- Make it required and unique
- Remove it from page layout and make read-only
- Create a new validation rule which forces Asset Name must be equal to custom field we built.

Alternatively this can be done by Apex trigger (before insert/update) which checks by query that there should not be field named the Asset Name entered in record. if exist throw error.

Comment: The first step fails. "Error: Field Name may not be used in this type of formula"

Comment: You can't use the Asset Name field in the default value formula of a field. You will have to create a new FORMULA field, of type text, and in it, insert the field Name (literally, the formula will just be "Name") the rest of this process, as complicated as it appears it is going to be(!) will work.

Comment: @SimonLawrence I missed that :)

Answer (score 3):

[Marty Chang has a way to do this declaratively:](https://frombelvideres4thfloor.blogspot.com/2010/12/enforcing-record-name-uniqueness-in.html)

It catches duplicates so long as they aren't in the same operation.

You can create an `Asset` Validation Rule with this formula condition:

```
Name == VLOOKUP(
    $ObjectType.Asset.Fields.Name,
    $ObjectType.Asset.Fields.Name,
    Name
)
&&
Id <> VLOOKUP(
    $ObjectType.Asset.Fields.Id,
    $ObjectType.Asset.Fields.Name,
    Name
)
```

Comment: It worked like a charm....

Answer (score 1):

```
AND(VLOOKUP($ObjectType.*Object_Name*.Fields.Name,
            $ObjectType.*Object_Name*.Fields.Name,
            Name) = Name,
   OR(
      ISNEW(),
      ISCHANGED(Name)
   )
)
```

​Works like a charm!